# HashMap does not get expected output?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I have the following 2 cases :

*Case 1:*

```
    HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>> mainMap  = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>>();
    
    HashMap <String, String> subMap  = new HashMap<String,String>();
    
    subMap.put("11", "12");
    subMap.put("13", "124");
    subMap.put("21", "122");
    subMap.put("14", "152");
    
    System.out.println("For One : "+subMap);
    mainMap.put("one", subMap);
    
    subMap.put("15", "152");
    subMap.put("17", "152");
    
    System.out.println("For Two : "+subMap);
    mainMap.put("two", subMap);
    
    System.out.println(mainMap);
```

I am expecting the following output :

```
For One : {21=122, 13=124, 14=152, 11=12}
For Two : {21=122, 17=152, 15=152, 13=124, 14=152, 11=12}
{two={21=122, 17=152, 15=152, 13=124, 14=152, 11=12}, one={21=122, 13=124, 14=152, 11=12}}
```

However, I am getting this output instead :

```
For One : {21=122, 13=124, 14=152, 11=12}
For Two : {21=122, 17=152, 15=152, 13=124, 14=152, 11=12}
{two={21=122, 17=152, 15=152, 13=124, 14=152, 11=12}, one={21=122, 17=152, 15=152, 13=124, 14=152, 11=12}}
```

*Case 2:*

I also tried the following :

```
HashMap<String,String> map12 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        
map12.put("1","1234");
map12.put("2","1234");
         
System.out.println("map12 : "+map12);
        
map12.put("3","1234");
```

And I got the correct output which was expected :

```
map12 : {2=1234, 1=1234}
```

Why does the code in `case1` not give the expected out but `case2` works perfectly fine?

Comment: This is normal you got this output because you are always modifying the same `subMap` object.

Comment: Also I don't know what's different in your case2. You're printing the map before adding the `"3" -> "1234"` key-value pair.

Comment: @ZouZou In Case 1 also i added some value of subMap to mainMap. I excepted the first 4 values of subMap to the one key of mainMap..

But it comes all the values in the one key

Comment: But you are adding the new content to the same `subMap`. You don't create a new reference. Every change you made in the `subMap` will be reflected.. Add `subMap  = new HashMap<String,String>(subMap);` after `mainMap.put("one", subMap);` to get your expected output.

Comment: Putting the `subMap` into the `mainMap` don't create a magical copy of the `subMap`.

Comment: @ZouZou My question is I am putting subMap(4 values) in to mainMap with key one. And subMap(6 values) into mainMap with key two. But I got both as same? why?

Comment: Because you are modifying the **same** `subMap` object, when you add the two more values in your `subMap` the map paired with key `"one"` is **also** modified. You manipulate the **same** reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value in your *mainMap* is a **reference** to a HashMap object. Any reference to that object (e.g. *subMap*) can change it.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the same hashmap, you have to create a new instance of it.

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>> mainMap  = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>>();

HashMap <String, String> subMap  = new HashMap<String,String>();

subMap.put("11", "12");
subMap.put("13", "124");
subMap.put("21", "122");
subMap.put("14", "152");

System.out.println("For One : "+subMap);
mainMap.put("one", subMap);

subMap  = new HashMap<String,String>(); /// <<<<<<<<
subMap.put("21", "122");
subMap.put("17", "152");
subMap.put("15", "152");
subMap.put("13", "124");
subMap.put("14", "152");
subMap.put("11", "12");

System.out.println("For Two : "+subMap);
mainMap.put("two", subMap);

System.out.println(mainMap);
```

Comment: -1 because check the output the person is expecting. your code will not give the same

Comment: I would just clone the subMap while putting the first entry. And also I think the user already know that he can achieve the  behavior the way you did, lets help him understand what mistake his code has and why?!

Answer (score 1):

If you are confused, this may help:

This line will create a HashMap object, and assigned a subMap reference to it.
    HashMap  subMap  = new HashMap();

subMap-------->[hashObject]

This line will add "one" as key, and subMap "reference" as value
    mainMap.put("one", subMap);

so, 
    mainMap.put("one", subMap---------------> [hashObject]

Then you prints the value assign to key "one" i.e. {21=122, 13=124, 14=152, 11=12}

Now, you are putting values to the same HashMap object [hashObject]

```
subMap.put("15", "152");

subMap.put("17", "152");
```

Now, map contains

```
{21=122, 17=152, 15=152, 13=124, 14=152, 11=12}
```

And then, you assigned it as:

```
mainMap.put("two", subMap---------------> [hashObject]
```

Try this:

```
System.out.println("For One : "+subMap);    

System.out.println("For Two : "+subMap);
```

Output:

```
For One : {11=12, 13=124, 14=152, 15=152, 17=152, 21=122}

For Two : {11=12, 13=124, 14=152, 15=152, 17=152, 21=122}
```

which is the same HashMap object, no new object is created and both "one" and "two" has value, a reference referring to the same object.

Please note that this is an object not a primitive.

```
int a = 10;
int b = a;
a++;
```

output:

```
a=11

b=10
```

but in case of object its reference not the object,

```
Object a = new Object();

Object b = a;
```

any change done using any of these references will effect the same object, because both are 
referring the same object.

In your case 2, you have first print the map and then added the next key-value.

Answer (score -1):

`HashMap` doesn't guarantee a specific order of the items stored inside. It's unordered.

Use `LinkedHashMap` instead. It stores the items in the order, in which they were inserted.

Read the Java Docs for more Infos:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html

Comment: he is not talking about order, but the umber of entries in map